# can students record the session in WizIQ or this facillity is available to instructors only

Tags: wiziq

I can see the record button for live session is available on the instructors screen but I want to know whether students can  record the session in WizIQ or this facillity is available to instructors only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct.

Features related to recordings come under **Virtual Classroom** based pricing and the same is not included in the **User** based pricing.

Between, the details are available in their official pricing page.

You could've easily found this out [here](https://www.wiziq.com/pricing/).